# How to resolve a dependency inside a Ninject Module?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am using Ninject 2 with Asp.Net MVC 3. I have following module.

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        //I need to get the 'configHelper' from Ninject Container. 
        IConfigHelper configHelper = ResolveConfigHelperHere();

        Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServiceImpl>().WithConstructorArgument("myArg", configHelper.MyProperty);

    }
}
```

How do we get the instance of 'IConfigHelper' which is already Bind in Ninject module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var helper = Kernel.Get<IConfigHelper>();
Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServiceImpl>().WithConstructorArgument(
    "myArg",
    helper.MyProperty
);
```

and here's a full example:

```
public interface IConfigHelper
{
    string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigHelper : IConfigHelper
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyService
{

}

public class MyServiceImpl : IMyService
{
    public MyServiceImpl(string myArg)
    {

    }
}

public class HelperModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IConfigHelper>()
            .To<ConfigHelper>()
            .WithPropertyValue("MyProperty", "foo");
    }
}

public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        var helper = Kernel.Get<IConfigHelper>();
        Bind<IMyService>()
            .To<MyServiceImpl>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("myArg", helper.MyProperty);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(
            new HelperModule(),
            new ServiceModule()
        );

        var service = kernel.Get<IMyService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get Kernel.Get<IConfigHelper>() method. Although I have Kernel.GetService method.

Comment: @Amitabh, that's strange. `Get<T>` is an extension method of `IResolutionRoot` which is implemented by `IKernel` and which is defined in the `Ninject` namespace. Which version are you using? For my test I fetched the latest Ninject NuGet package and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Darin: I have got Ninject.MVC3 - 2.2.0.3  from Nuget

Comment: @Amitabh, mine is assembly version 2.2.0.0 and file version 2.2.1.0 with file size of 106496 bytes. Do you have `using Ninject;` on your page?

Comment: @Darin: Thanks. It was just the issue of using Ninject..?

Comment: @Amitabh, yes `.Get<T>` is an extension method so the proper namespace must be brought into scope in order to use it.

Comment: @Darin: do you not consider this somewhat of an anti-pattern? Loading `ServiceModule` will fail unless `HelperModule` is already loaded, but this cannot be enforced at compile time and would not be apparent to any consumer of `StandardModule`.

Comment: sorry that should read `ServiceModule`, not `StandardModule` in the last sentence above.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet : It does feel weird that modules would not publish their own dependendies. Is there any best practice for this situation?